# I want to move one table from SQL developer on computer A to SQL developer on computer B

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to move a table from a database on SQL Developer on my laptop to my desktop's SQL developer

[image]

The files to generate the tables and the schema I no longer have access to so I feel like this is my only option. But I can't figure out how to do this smoothly, is it even possible? I'm also open to just recreating the table

It should be simple but I can't figure it out. I'm a complete beginner so I suspect this has something to do with having the table connecting to the other tables in the model which is why this can't be done easily or requires more steps than I'm think it'll take.

Here are the tables details..
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: **NEVER** create tables in the `SYS` schema. Always create a separate user.

Comment: Your database containing your tables is Oracle. Your desktop tool for querying and displaying results is SQL Developer. The data isn't in SQL Developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Developer is **NOT** a database.

SQL Developer is a client application that is used to access one or more databases.

There are many options including:

- Backup your database and then copy the backup and restore it on the laptop.
- In SQL Developer, use "Tools" then "Database Export".
- Run `SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE', TABLE_NAME) FROM USER_TABLES;` and copy the generated DDL statements to the laptop and generate the tables.
- Right-click on an individual table in SQL Developer and generate the DDL for the table and save it to a file and then run the DDL statement on the laptop.

Comment: So i've tried the 3rd option you mentioned where I write the query. I wrote 
SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', 'SHAREHOLDER') from user_tables;
And that has a result that's been running for the last 20 minutes where in the result, I currently have 600 records saying "Create tables "SYS"."SHAREHOLDER" ("SHAREHOLDER_ID" NUMBER(6,0)..."
And it keeps making more, do I just wait for it to finish?

Comment: @ZaneK Since your schema diagram has table names `SYS.SHAREHOLDER` etc., I assume that you are connected as the `SYS` user. This is **VERY** bad practice (as making changes to the `SYS` schema can make your database unusable) and is also the source of your problem because it is trying to generate the DDL statements for **ALL** the system tables as well as the tables you created. Don't wait for it to finish; cancel the query and add `WHERE table_name IN ('SHAREHOLDER', 'TRADE', 'COMPANY')` to the query and re-run it. Then when you recreate the tables on the laptop **DO NOT** use the `SYS` user.